# How can I resize image in my article in Joomla?

Tags: image, joomla, resize, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

I have a problem, so I've Homepage that contains All articles in evidence. The images into the article is not resized to adapt it at template.
If you know any free solutions, I thank him!

This is my site:

http://www.iismeucci.gov.it/

Answer (score 2):

In your template css file, you should add the following code:

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: I'd add **height: auto;** so images won't get streched